# Xcode 5 can't find an armv7s architecture in a static library even though file and lipo say it's there

Tags: ios, linker, xcode5, static-libraries

I'm trying to integrate [BugshotKit](https://github.com/marcoarment/BugshotKit) into my iOS project. I've built the static library on my machine, included it in my project directory, set my library and header search paths appropriately and added `-lBugshotKit` to my Other Linker Flags. But when I build, I'm getting the following error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file ...Project/BugshotKit/libBugshotKit.a, missing required architecture armv7s in file .../BugshotKit/libBugshotKit.a (2 slices)
```

This strikes me as odd, because `lipo` thinks it's there:

```
$ xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info libBugshotKit.a
Architectures in the fat file: libBugshotKit.a are: armv7 armv7s x86_64 arm64
```

Note also how Xcode thinks there are "2 slices" where `lipo` (and `file`, for what it's worth) thinks there are four.

What is going wrong and how might I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Xcode was just being Xcode and `Product/Clean Build Folder` (⌥⇧⌘K) fixed it.